# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(' Im getting error on below code

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
function _initAutoload() {
    Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader;
    new ( array ('namespace' => 'Eicra', 'basePath' => bbddbgdiaa( __FILE__ ) ) );
    $autoloader = ;
    return $autoloader;
}
```

In the above function i m getting a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '('.

how to fix the error . please Revert me.

**Please check the full code i m getting lot of error . because of new how to solve this please help me..**

```
<?php

class Install extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap {
    private $_installed = false;

    function _initAutoload() {
        Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader;
        new ( array( 'namespace' => 'Eicra', 'basePath' => bbddbgdiaa( __FILE__ ) ) );
        $autoloader = ;
        return $autoloader;
    }

    function _initSystem() {
        Zend_Currency::setcache( Eicra_View_Helper_Cache::getsystemcache(  ) );
    }

    function _initCheckInstall() {
        if (cjajebcjhc( APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/config.ini' )) {
            Zend_Config_Ini;
            new ( APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/config.ini' );
            $config = ;

            if (( null != $config->install && null != $config->install->date )) {
                $this->_installed = true;
            }
        }

    }

    function _initResourceAutoload() {
        Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource;
        new ( array( 'basePath' => LIBRARY_PATH, 'namespace' => 'Eicra', 'resourceTypes' => array( 'global' => array( 'path' => 'Sessions/', 'namespace' => 'Global' ), 'acl' => array( 'path' => 'Modules/Acls/', 'namespace' => 'Libs' ), 'helpers' => array( 'path' => 'Modules/Helpers/', 'namespace' => 'VHelper' ), 'dbtable' => array( 'path' => 'Default/Models/Dbtables/', 'namespace' => 'Abstract' ), 'api' => array( 'path' => 'Apis/', 'namespace' => 'Lib' ), 'utility' => array( 'path' => 'Utility/', 'namespace' => 'File' ), 'routing' => array( 'path' => 'Modules/Menu/', 'namespace' => 'Menu' ), 'import' => array( 'path' => 'Import/', 'namespace' => 'Import' ), 'importerFactory' => array( 'path' => 'Import/', 'namespace' => 'Import' ), 'adapter' => array( 'path' => 'Import/Adapter', 'namespace' => 'Import_Adapter' ), 'mysqli' => array( 'path' => 'Import/Adapter/Mysqli', 'namespace' => 'Import_Adapter_Mysqli' ), 'license' => array( 'path' => 'Version/', 'namespace' => 'License' ) ) ) );
        $resourceLoader = ;
        return $resourceLoader;
    }

    function _initRoutes() {
        Zend_Controller_Front::getinstance(  );
        $front = ;
        $front->getRouter(  );
        $router = ;
        $router->removeDefaultRoutes(  );

        if ($this->_installed == true) {
            Zend_Controller_Router_Route;
            ( 'install_step_already', new $router->addRoute( '/', array( 'module' => 'default', 'controller' => 'Install', 'action' => 'stepinstalled' ) ) );
        }
        else {
            Zend_Controller_Router_Route;
            ( 'install_step1', new $router->addRoute( '/', array( 'module' => 'default', 'controller' => 'Install', 'action' => 'step1' ) ) );
        }

        Zend_Controller_Router_Route;
        ( 'install_step2', new $router->addRoute( '/step2/', array( 'module' => 'default', 'controller' => 'Install', 'action' => 'step2' ) ) );
        Zend_Controller_Router_Route;
        ( 'install_step3', new $router->addRoute( '/step3/', array( 'module' => 'default', 'controller' => 'Install', 'action' => 'step3' ) ) );
        Zend_Controller_Router_Route;
        ( 'install_step4', new $router->addRoute( '/step4/', array( 'module' => 'default', 'controller' => 'Install', 'action' => 'step4' ) ) );
        Zend_Controller_Router_Route;
        ( 'install_step5', new $router->addRoute( '/step5/', array( 'module' => 'default', 'controller' => 'Install', 'action' => 'step5' ) ) );
        Zend_Controller_Router_Route;
        ( 'install_step6', new $router->addRoute( '/step6/', array( 'module' => 'default', 'controller' => 'Install', 'action' => 'step6' ) ) );
    }

    function _initLanguage() {
        Eicra_View_Helper_Translator;
        $translator = new (  );
        Zend_Registry::set( 'translator', $translator );
        Exception {
            echo $e->getMessage(  );
            exit(  );
            return null;
        }
    }

    function _initView() {
        Zend_Layout::startmvc( array( 'layoutPath' => APPLICATION_PATH . DS . 'layouts' . DS . 'scripts' . DS . 'default' ) );
        Zend_Layout::getmvcinstance(  )->setLayout( 'install' );
        Zend_Registry::set( 'front_template', 'Default' );
        Eicra_License_Version;
        ( 'version', new Zend_Registry::set(  ) );
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: what is `new (` meant to express?

Comment: What's with this: `new ( array ('namespace' => 'Eicra', 'basePath' => bbddbgdiaa( __FILE__ ) ) );`?

Comment: You're using the `new` keyword wrong; Judging from your code, you should learn PHP first ;)

Comment: Was going to submit an answer until I saw everyone getting nuked by downvotes.

Comment: Downvotes are the result when people try to offer _anything_ they can think of that _might_ be related to a question as an "answer".

Comment: @danielsmile Hah, no downvotes yet! :D

Comment: hey guys please help to answer this question how to solve. dont put down vote and just answer if you know

Comment: This a zend framework code please help guys . If you know or ur expert  just help dont overrated @arkascha, danielsmile , Shomz.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, this is wrong:

```
new ( array ('namespace' => 'Eicra', 'basePath' => bbddbgdiaa( __FILE__ ) ) );
```

Wrong syntax, and useless. And that's why you're getting the error.

---

Some advice now (take it as a comment):

Read here about using Zend Autoloader: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html

Seems like this is what you need (but go over the docs in detail):

```
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

$autoloader->pushAutoloader(array ('namespace' => 'Eicra', 'basePath' => bbddbgdiaa( __FILE__ ) ) );
```